# Error: This site has not been shared with you, when creating new site collection

Tags: site-collection, administration

I am logged in as a the SharePoint service account, and I tried to create a new team site of type team site, but I am getting the following error :

> This site has not been shared with you.

Although I defined myself as the site collection admin. Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: As you say, you've defined yourself as the site collection admin, but you're logging as the *Sharepoint Service Account* - which is not **your** account.

Comment: After the site name, add **/_layouts/15/settings.aspx** and see if you can enter the settings page

Comment: but i have created a community site using the same account and it worked well !!

Comment: and what is the problem with being the service account + the site collection admin ? as this is my case.

Answer (score 1):

I just  created the CS --> specify and user as the admin --> changed the admin back to my user name, and it worked fine!