# Site Could not be Created in Site Collection

Tags: powershell, site

I tried to add a site in a site collection but unfortunately it isn't working. SharePoint allows me to add a site, but when I want to check the created site, no site exists at all.

The procedures I followed are:

1- I created the web application with "servername:portnumber"

2- I created the web site with "servername:portnumber/sites/sitename"

How can I do that with PowerShell if it is not possible with admin?

Comment: Are getting any error while creating site? With what name you want create site?

Comment: non gave a message at the end this site is not shared with

Comment: So your site collection is created successfully or you are getting this error on creating site collection?

Comment: is not created when i get back to my site web application i could not find my creatd site

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/76700/error-this-site-has-not-been-shared-with-you-when-creating-new-site-collection

Answer (score 0):

For creating site collection using powershell you can follow following link:

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/cc263165(v=office.14).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/cc263165%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

For creating site using powershell you can follow following link:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/09/21/use-sharepoint-2010-powershell-cmdlets-to-get-and-manage-sites.aspx

http://www.bluedoglimited.com/SharePointThoughts/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=340